# Git push specific branch hang on git extension

Tags: git, push, git-push, head

I strugle with git push with one bigger branch with two commits but I can normally git pull, rebase, fetchs on this specific branch. Moreover, rest of my branches work well. I can push them to server. I use Git Extensions program for git. I click git push and i get message that Total oraz delta is 100% but console hangs on and cannot complite. I am not currently in work I cannot send screen. It looks like waiting thread or while(true).

So far I tried:

- updated git
- updated Git Extensions
- reset computer
- git gc
- git prune
- git push Head or something like this (I dont remember)

**I wanted to cherry pick it to another branch to push but also it doesn't work.**
I can manually copy paste to another branch.
**My suspect is: HEAD.** 
I dont have much experience with git. I use pull/rebase/cherry pick. 
I hope to find solution, because handy coping is cre**y.

Please help me

BR,

Cenarius

Comment: Could you please put the console output of `git push` into the question?

Comment: thanks for replay, I can do it on Monday